# Image navigation in c#.net and sqlserver

Tags: c#

creating simple image navigation system in c# and sqlserver database. i ran in to the problem with
  PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ms); i attached the image below what is error was shown.

[image]

```
 private void showPosition()
      {
          Label3.Text = cv.Position + 1 + "of" + cv.Count;

          byte[] arrPicture = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[cv.Position]["image"];
          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrPicture);
          PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ms);

              PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
              PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;             
      }
```

Comment: `Image.FromFile` expects a path not a memory stream. Try `Image.FromStream`

Comment: You probably meant to use `FromStream`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image.FromFile` Expects a filename (string) as parameter. Please use `Image.FromStream` method instead.

```
 PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: See documentation for [Image.FromStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: byte[] arrPicture = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[cv.Position]["image"];  this line error There is no row at position -1.